# 5 and 7 point regular 3d shape

Tags: geometry, 3d

Assume a situation where there are *n* balls tied to a point individually using strings of equal lengths.

Each ball repels the other ball.

Now,

For *n*=2, the balls would form a *line* - 180˚,

*n*=3, the balls would form a *triangle* - 120˚,

*n*=4, the balls would form a *tetrahedron* - 108˚30'28", and so on.

*n*=6 - octahedron - 90˚

*n*=8 - cube - 54.74˚

My question is, what would the shape be for *n*=5 and *n*=7?

Is there a name for that shape? What would the angle formed be?

Comment: You are assuming there is a unique position of equilibrium for that values of $n$. My guess is that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that, for I thought that should be the case.
I can't think of a reason why there should not be an equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a paper that answers that question for $n = 5$, I believe (at least if you assume that all the strings have the same length):

https://www.math.brown.edu/reschwar/Papers/electron.pdf

The shape is apparently called "the triangular
bi-pyramid" and consists (after a suitable rotation) of the north and south poles, and three points lying on an equilateral triangle on the equator.

My guess is that there's no known-and-proved answer for $n = 7$, and given the difficulty of the $n = 5$ case (and Schwartz's remark about a "sense of diminishing returns"), I wouldn't guess that there's anyone seriously working on it, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The shape triangular bipyramid has, as far as I know, unequal lengths of string.
The axial and equatorial points have different lengths.

Thus, my doubt.

Comment: The equal length strings in your question connect the balls to a central point, not to the other balls. So the final configuration will live on a  sphere. The triangular bipyramid is not a counterexample even though edge lengths are not all equal.

Comment: @EthanBolker, thank you, I got it. 


On that basis, for n=7, the answer might be pentagonal bi-pyramidal.

Comment: It might, but I wouldn't bet on it. There seems to be no conjecture in the paper linked in this answer. I wonder if there is one in its references. For large $n$ the bipyramid is clearly bad because points on the equator are too close together. In fact the bipyramid isn't the answer for $n=8$.

Comment: I'll bet that a small perturbation of the pentagon (say...in the latitude-direction only) will lead to an improved "score", even though it'd be a lot easier to show if the number of vertices on the equator was even. :(